# Can you persist individual states in redux persist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

So I am using redux toolkit and redux persist to persist certain reducers but the problem is I don't want to persist the entire reducer but instead just the states inside of the reducer

the code where im whitlisting(persisting} certain reducers

src/app/store.js

```
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storageSession from "redux-persist/es/storage/session";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

import registerReducer from "../features/register.slice";
import verificationReducer from "../features/verification.slice";

// Combining reducers
const reducers = combineReducers({
  register: registerReducer,
  verification: verificationReducer,
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage: storageSession,
  whitelist: ["verification"], // Slicers that will be persisted
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

// Creating store
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
  middleware: [thunk],
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: from the docs it looks like the nested persist functionality should be able to do this: https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#nested-persists

Comment: Thank you very much i had my head bashing over this

Answer (score 0):

one Method is:-

if you don't want to make any state persist then you can just erase the value of state once reload the window by dispatching actions.

like this:-
i have one action **search** and state name is **searchedvalue**

when i want to set the searchedvalue then we can call searchHandler
but once the window reloaded then in useEffect we dispatch same action but set the value to null

```
const searchHandler=(e)=>{
e.preventDefault();
dispatch(search(searchedValue));}

useEffect(()=>{ dispatch(search(null)); },[])
```